# How I can save user in my session inside a controller in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, session

I'm trying to implement login form in my Symfony project. But I don't know how exactly to use my session in my controller. Actually, I don't know what is the session as a whole in Symfony.

I created the login form and it checks correctly if a user exists but when I try to save it into the session my IDE tells me that $session is Undefined variable I included "use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;"
but it didn't help. If I write $session = new Session(); $session->start(); an exception in my browser says that the session is already started. Maybe I don't use session in the right way or it can't be used in the controllers. How to fix it and how to use the session and when and where the session in Symfony starts. Here is my code.

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use App\Form\UserType;
use App\Form\UserLoginType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

class UserController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/EventsAndPeople/task_success", name="task_success")
     */
    public function succsess()
    {
        return $this->render('home/Succes.html.twig');
    }

/**
* @Route("/EventsAndPeople/Login", name="Login")
*/
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $user = new User();
    $form = $this->createForm(UserLoginType::class, $user);

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
          $notTrueUser = $form->getData();
        $user = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(User::class)
            ->findOneByPasswordAndEmailAndUsername($notTrueUser->getPassword(),$notTrueUser->getEmail(),$notTrueUser->getUsername());
        if (!$user) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException(
                'No product found for this email and password '
            );
        }
        $session->set($user);
        return $this->redirectToRoute('task_success');
    }
    return $this->render('home/LoginForm.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
}
```

I thought that if the session is already started I can use it in the controller but my IDE shows me its wrong

Comment: Have you looked at the SecurityBundle at all?  Lots of functionality which will save lots of time and result in what will almost certainly be a more secure app.

Comment: Yes, I looked but I want to do it the simple way first and then when I understand how the sessions work I can try SecurityBundle. I'm new with Symfony and I don't know exactly how to do the login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, you must create the object of calls session

like this

```
 $session = new Session();
```

or(For your issues I guess you need this statement)

```
 $session = $request->getSession();
```

and then defined key with value:->

```
   $session->set('user', $user);
```

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot but when I define it with $session = new Session(); how can I use it in another controller and more importantly how many times I need to define it.

Comment: When you want to use session in another controller you can use it:$session->get('user');  user is key ..